# C GTK2 frustrated with gnome documentation

Tags: c, gtk

I have been attempting to create an app using C in Code::Blocks on Win7.

Can anyone please point me to a better documentation then the gnome site? Or failing that, can someone point me to a place I can see which signals are allowed for which widgets?

I recently wrote an app using Python and found TKinter to be very good, and every time I searched Google for help on TKinter the documentation was easy to read and understandable.

The gnome GTK documentation, however, is really bad. Yes, it does describe each function, but doesn't lead you to the other parts needed to get a full understanding of the function.

They go into great detail in some cases, actually including an entire program as an example (without comments in the code I might add,) totally obscuring the forest trying to describe the tree.

I don't want to get too bogged down in a detail of my problem now, but this is an example of my frustration.

Specifically, I am attaching a signal to an entry widget, and I can find the g_signal_connect declaration that gives the parameters needed, like the instance, the_signal, the handler and such, but nowhere does it say WHICH signals can be used.

I guess it is because each widget may use a different subset of signals for the signal, but, to date. I have not found even a list of signals available let alone which ones can be used on which widgets.

I can find the gtk_entry_new() definition, but again, that description doesn't give a list of allowable signals. Just how to call it.

I saw an example that uses the "insert_text" signal, but that isn't really right, another site says there is an "activate" signal, but that only works if the user presses enter, not if the user clicks elsewhere in the window.

Any help is appreciated.

Mark.

Comment: GTK2 is pretty old now but there are some old books on the topic you can probably pick up second hand for next to nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I've already seen that doc issue. The way the doc is generated has changed and it seems this broke some parts of GTK+ 2 generated doc. Now, you shouldn't be using GTK+ 2 in the first place. GTK+ 3 has been the stable release for years now, and GTK+ 2 should only be used in legacy projects. GTK+ 4 in on its way to be released this year.

To know which signals can be used on which widget, you just have to go to the "signals" section of the documentation page of that widget. For example, here are the [signals specific to GtkEntry](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry.signals). Each widget doc page has a top bar with several section shortcuts, with links to the sections you want:

> Top  |  Description  |  Object Hierarchy  |  Implemented Interfaces  |  Properties  |  Style Properties  |  Signals

You see the last one is about signals.

Now this is only for signals specific to the class. This is object-oriented programming, so you can also use the signals from the parent classes as well. Just click on the "Object Hierarchy" link and you'll be sent on the inheritance diagram of the class. From there you may explore the parent classes, and then their signals.

You may also want to install the Devhelp program, which give you a search-as-you-type entry and gathers the docs of lots of other libraries on which GTK+ and the GNOME platform depend (cairo, pango, etc.). Install it with your package manager, and you'll have access to offline help for all the development packages you installed, and at the versions you're really using.